# Using React, click the first input show the second input, how to auto focus to the second input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ace-editor

Using react, i click the first input to show the second input(react-ace editor), how to make the second input(react-ace editor) automatically gets focus and the first input lost focus ?

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        hidden: true,
        value: props.value
    };
}
...
 render() {

 return <div className="form-group">
     <Input  onClick={() => this.showEditor()}  onChange={() => false} value={this.props.value}/>
     <div className={classNames({'hidden': this.state.hidden})}>
     <ReactAceEditor
        onLoad={(editor) => {
          editor.focus();
        }} 
     />
   </div>
   </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass `focus={true}` to the AceEditor, and don't render it until the `input` is clicked. Once the `AceEditor` is rendered, it will get focused and thus cause the `input` blur.

Have tested and it works.

```
<input onClick={() => this.setState({ show: true })}/>
        { 
          this.state.show &&
            <AceEditor
              focus
              mode="javascript"
              theme="monokai"
              onChange={(newValue) => this.code=newValue}
              name="UNIQUE_ID_OF_DIV"
              editorProps={{$blockScrolling: true}}
            />
        }
```